# Finding the limit points of the set $\{(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n})^{m+n} : m,n\in\mathbb N\}$

Tags: general-topology

I have to find the limit points of the set
$\{(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n})^{m+n}: m,n\in\mathbb N\}$. When $m = n$ and $n$ tends to infinity we find that $0$ is a limit point. Also when we fix $m$ as $1$, $e$ is a limit point. What happens when $m$ is greater than $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ and $e$ are the only limit points.

If $x$ is a limit point then there exist $m_k,n_k$ such that $n_k+m_k \to \infty$ and $(\frac  1{n_k}+\frac  1{n_k})^{n_k+m_k} \to x$. If $m_k \geq 3$ and $n_k \geq 3$ for infinitely many $k$ then $(\frac  1{n_k}+\frac  1{n_k}) \leq \frac  2 3 <1$ which forces $x$ to be $0$. Can you  finish?

Comment: :How is 1 a limit point?

Comment: @sxccalmat1100 Sorry, I meant to say $0$ and $e$.

Comment: I understood the rest of your argument.